# Cannot compile class in separate files

Tags: java, eclipse, command-prompt

My problem: when I use Eclipse, I create separate .java files(3 normal class, 1 class contain main method). If I run by Eclipse, it works. But when I try compiling it by Command Prompt, it doesn't work. As if it don't know where to find the data from other class.
Ex:
class one in one.java , compile ->OK
class two extends one in two.java, compile->they don't know what is 'one'
I try compiling by Command Prompt bc before I use Eclipse, I use Notepad and Command Prompt.
Can you give me an answer? Thank you very much !!!

Comment: can you please provice the command line prompt you are using? (And just as a hint, you might want to use gradle or maven to care about compiling on command line level)

Answer (score 0):

You must write the path of the main file and run it, for example:

c:\windows\documents\eclipse-workspace....\javac Main.java

Then type "java Main" command to run it

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I found another question just like mine on Stack overflow, and I solved it so I forgot my question for a very long time. Thank you very much because you give me a very helpful and accurate solution.